# Table is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am getting this error in wordpress phpMyadmin

```
#145 - Table './DB_NAME/wp_posts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

When I login to phpMyadmin, it says wp_posts is "in use"

My website is currently down because of this.

I googled this problem, but I don't see the "repair" button on phpMyadmin. Please let me know how to fix this. I am not sure where to issue PHP command. Please advise, my proficiency with PHP is very basic.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Here is where the repair button is:

[image]

Comment: You will probably need to restart mysql/mariadb (sudo systemctl restart mysql/mariadb) to make the problem go away in the status (sudo systemctl status mysql/mariadb). Even after everything is working...

Answer (score 227):

Run this from your server's command line:

```
 mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases
```

Comment: To avoid a 'access denied' error, you might have to add the username and password to this command. `mysqlcheck -uroot -p --repair --all-databases` and supply the password.

Comment: slight edit: mysqlcheck -u root -p --repair --all-databases

Answer (score 156):

I had the same issue when my server free disk space available was 0

You can use the command (there must be ample space for the mysql files)

```
REPAIR TABLE `<table name>`;
```

for repairing individual tables

Comment: Helpful, I had this problem with a Drupal v7.6x UC table, which suddenly played up; issued the REPAIR TABLE command as above in the phpMyAdmin SQL console and fixed it. Thank goodness for stackoverflow!! Cheers!

Comment: Or the error "The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair"

Answer (score 35):

Connect to your server via SSH

then connect to your mysql console

and

```
USE user_base
REPAIR TABLE TABLE;
```

## -OR-

If there are a lot of broken tables in current database:

```
mysqlcheck -uUSER -pPASSWORD  --repair --extended user_base
```

If there are a lot of broken tables in a lot of databases:

```
mysqlcheck -uUSER -pPASSWORD  --repair --extended -A
```

Comment: Do not put passwords in command line, they are then saved in the history in a non-secured way and location. mysql commands lets you pass the parameter `-p` alone, and will then ask you for your password.

Answer (score 22):

When I got this error:

> #145 - Table '.\engine\phpbb3_posts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

I ran this command in PhpMyAdmin to fix it:

```
REPAIR TABLE phpbb3_posts;
```

Answer (score 8):

This means your MySQL table is corrupted and you need to repair it. Use

```
myisamchk -r /DB_NAME/wp_posts
```

from the command line. While you running the repair you should shut down your website temporarily so that no new connections are attempted to your database while its being repaired.

Comment: I asked this to the comment above but I think he is signed out, so asking it to you again.  "Thanks a lot, my site is back online again. One question though, as the database was corrupted and I repaired it again, should I be worried about anything? Should I investigate if that made anything else break? Or this should have taken care of everything?"

Comment: You should not be worried about anything. Once database is repaired your site will work again. It may get corrupted again at some point, it happens, just repair it again. Also do backups regularly and you will be fine

Answer (score 5):

**Here is simple steps.**

Go to phpmyadmin and checked that table which one crushed and then select Repair table option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Nican
you can follow the given steps. It works some times. I have faced the same Error many times in my experience. It’s not easy to find the corrupted table in the MySQL database. Low disk space could be a major cause of this error.

You can use a command to repair the corrupted or crashed MySQL table.

```
# myisamchk -r <table name>
```

Note: r means recovery mode

If it does not work, You can go for a difficult repair.

Step 1 – Shift a database to a safe location.
Step 2- Create a new empty data and index file.
Step 3- Copy the old data file back onto the newly created data file

Note: You must maintain the main backup copy to recover if something goes wrong.

If both solutions do not work for you, I strongly recommend you go for a stellar repair for MySQL. This one is my best friend in my bad situations. It saves my data many times