# MySQL Table marked as crashed, repair fails

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I had a problem similar to this in MySQL 5.7: [Table is marked as crashed and should be repaired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357270/table-is-marked-as-crashed-and-should-be-repaired/19955330)

When I used the tips in the thread to repair, the following happens:

Query:

```
REPAIR TABLE `<table>`
```

Result:

```
"database.<table>"  "repair"    "Error"  "Table ‘database.<table>' doesn't exist"

"database.<table>"  "repair"    "status" "Operation failed"
```

When I click on the table in HeidiSQL, I can view it normally. It only fails when I run a query.

Thanks all

Comment: Did you forget to put in **an actual / valid name** for `<table>`? ie. `REPAIR TABLE AwesomeSauce`

Comment: Unfortunately no, I wish it was that simple

Comment: Unless it is a 'sensitive' table name, it'd probably be good to update the post with the *actual* query and actual error messages..

Comment: They are actually fairly sensitive, but I triple checked, the names are consistent, and all I changed was the actual names to database and table in the post.