# "use db_name" fails with error #1046 on MySQL, message = "no database selected"

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.4, mysql-error-1146, mysql-error-1046

I haven't used MySQL for a while, so forgive me if this is a silly issue with a simple solution. I have checked similar questions on the site, and in the majority of cases, the asker simply forgot to create or specify the database. This is not the case here.

I get the message

```
 Error: #1046 No database selected
```

After running the following instruction

```
 USE db_name;
```

For example:

```
 USE test;
```

I've tried several databases, but I get the same error with all of them. Creating databases works, that is, the database is created, but the same error message is still shown. If I try to SELECT * on a table from an existing database after specifying it:

```
USE db_name;
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

I get the error:

```
#1146 - Table 'db_name.table_name' doesn't exist
```

I'm using MariaDB, version 10.4.14 with root user.

Comment: that means there is no `table_name` in db you selected before - as the error stated:  Table 'db_name.table_name' doesn't exist

Comment: I'm looking right at the table on the database list in the left side menu. The table exists. And it's not the main issue anyway.

Comment: Have you stopped and restarted everything?

Comment: @P.Salmon I did. The error message #1046 is still shown, but at least the query is executed, and I get the table content. I also get the error  

Error: #145 Table '.\db_name\table_name' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Comment: How to solve the crashed table is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357270/table-is-marked-as-crashed-and-should-be-repaired